# Is it possible to deserialize RFC3339 full-date field of an request json body to some java date class within msf4j application?

Tags: jackson, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

I wonder if it is possible to deserialize RFC3339 full-date field of an request json body to some java date class within msf4j application?

My model looks like:

```
class Model {
  java.util.Date date;
  ...
}
```

Service looks like:

```
@Path("/")
class Service {
  @POST
  @Path("/models")
  @Consumes({"application/json"})
  public Response(Model m) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And when I do post, it returns me : "Error in executing request: POST /models"

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK jackson deserialization doesn't supported by the MSF4J. You can do a feature request issue for jackson support